# Subscriber and publisher in a file

Tags: ros, pose, ros-kinetic, geometry-msgs, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 16.04  kinetic
I am trying to get pose information from Phantom omni device and send the pose information to my robotic arm in gazebo.
For now, my subscribe node works well but I would like to add publisher part in the same file.
Do I need to use different nodeHandle with the subscriber for the publisher?
Can I put the following line things into the main function and use the callback function for the publisher?
`ros::Publisher endPose_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("pose", 100, popub_callback);`

Here is my subscribe node to get pose information from Phantom omni

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr> pose;

double x_current = 0;
double y_current = 0;
double z_current = 0;
double x_quat = 0;
double y_quat = 0;
double z_quat = 0;
double w_quat = 0;

void po_callback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr& msg) {

   ROS_INFO_STREAM("Received pose: " << msg);
    x_current = msg->pose.position.x;
    y_current = msg->pose.position.y;
    z_current = msg->pose.position.z;
    x_quat = msg->pose.orientation.x;
    y_quat = msg->pose.orientation.y;
    z_quat = msg->pose.orientation.z;
    w_quat = msg->pose.orientation.w;
   
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(x_current);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(y_current);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(z_current);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(x_quat);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(y_quat);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(z_quat);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(w_quat);

  // pose.push_back(msg);
}
    
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "pose_subscriber");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber endPose_sub = nh.subscribe("/omniEthernet/pose/", 100, po_callback);

    ros::spin();

    return(0);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319531/subscriber-and-publisher-in-a-file/) by [gariym](https://answers.ros.org/users/40616/gariym/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

> Do I need to use different nodeHandle with the subscriber for the publisher?

No, you can subscribe and publish with the same node handler.

> Can I put the following line things into the main function and use the callback function for the publisher?

in the case that you want to publish the coming message with same rate or you want to publish it  whenever you receive it, one solution is to declare  a global publisher (outside main() ):

```
ros::Publisher endPose_pub;
```

then inside the main, you can define it as

```
endPose_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("pose", 100, popub_callback);
```

then you can use the publisher inside the callback and publish your message.

---

Originally posted by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) with karma: 146 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gariym](https://answers.ros.org/users/40616/gariym/) on 2019-03-26**:
It really helps a lot. I know what I need to do now.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-03-27**:
Please accept the answer if it solved your problem, otherwise it stays listed as "Unanswered"